# How to copy to a folder on a Sunday but delete on every other day?

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy

How can I move/copy a file from D:\WindowsImageBackup\ to D:\Included\ if it's a Sunday or delete D:\Included\ if it's any other day?

The scenario is: An automatic backup to a remote server runs once a day. I want a certain file to be backed up only once a week, on a Sunday (it's the Windows image backup). I have excluded the folder where the file lives (D:\WindowsImageBackup).

Comment: Why not use a Windows scheduled task for this? It's much easier to schedule, and you can have it run right before the automatic backup is supposed to run. A scheduled task can run at an exact time, and can be easily configured to run only one day (or all other 6 days) extremely easily. This would make it a matter of writing two simple batch files (one to be run on Sunday, the other to run every other day) and scheduling those batch files to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set dow=%date:~0,3%
if "%dow%" equ "Sun" xcopy /y "D:\WindowsImageBackup\*.* "D:\Included\" & goto eof
echo del "D:\Included\*.*" /y
:eof
```

Note that this works only if your system language is English, as it does a literal comparison of the day part of `Date` against the value `Sun`, and of course isn't localized.

Also, see my comment to your question about this perhaps being better for a scheduled task (as errors would stop it and write to the Event Log).